# Is \$j\sin(\omega t)\$ just \$\sin(\omega t+90)\$?

Tags: math

If so, then the Euler formula is much less aesthetic in my view...
And, in IQ modulation, is the Q signal \$j\sin(\omega t)\$, or \$\sin(\omega t)\$?

Comment: no, it's not. basic math: wt is real, so sin(wt) is real, so j·sin(wt) is imaginary. sin(wt+90) is real, and since a non-zero imaginary number is not a real number, your title answers itself.

Comment: also, this has nothing to do with optoelectronics, so I'm removing that tag :)

Comment: sin(wt+90) is cos(wt), or it might be -cos(wt), ICBA to think about the sign.

Comment: by the way, regarding your Q signal: it's neither. The Q signal is the result of mixing with a harmonic oscillation that's orthogonal to that used for the inphase branch.

Comment: Thanks. This question was actually asking about the real meaning of the imaginary. Some people do interpret multiplying j as turning 90 degrees - not a reliable and comprehensive way of interpreting it, though. My understanding on this is that imaginary numbers are not simply turning the base real numbers by pi/2. We just picked the y-axis to represent imaginary numbers so as to construct a complex plane. It is not turning the vector on a real plane by pi/2.

Comment: Yes, the Q signal should be cos(wt) which is the quadrature of the in-phase signal sin(wt).

Comment: @MarcusMüller -- if \$sin \left(\omega t\right) \$ has an imaginary component, then \$j sin \left(\omega t\right) \$ has a real component (\$j\times j\$)

Answer (score 0):

Signals in electronics are real voltages and currents.  If one wants to make something that acts like a mathematical, “complex signal”, one way of doing it is to use two channels, labeling one “real” and one “imaginary”. But, these are just labels.  For example, one can create a signal,  \$\exp(j\omega t)\$, by making a \$\cos(\omega t)\$ signal and labeling it “real”, and a \$\sin(\omega t)\$ signal (which of course is just a phase shifted \$\cos\$) , and labeling it “imaginary”. Doing the appropriate operations on the two channels can be equivalent to doing complex math on \$\exp(j\omega t)\$. Now our mathematics and our circuits are in correspondence!